# Getting extra information with REST API call

Tags: rest, listdata.svc

So I'm trying to get TeamCalendar information out of Sharepoint in a single call, but I can't get the Attendees out. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/sites/ecengprodsoft/mt/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TeamCalendar(32)",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Which gives me all the information about an event apart from `Attendees`, `Category`, `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy`which show as `[object Object]` but have no useful sub-information inside apart from the URI call to get the right data.

So for example, if I call `/sites/ecengprodsoft/mt/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TeamCalendar(32)/Attendees` I get the information I want, but I don't want to have to perform a separate call for each item in the TeamCalendar.

Is there a way to get all the information, including attendees from the TeamCalendar with one call? Perhaps there's some parameters that I can add?

Note that using SOAP this is possible in one call, it grabs all the information.

Comment: did you try to add the some params more? Take a look on this link http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/

Comment: That's nice, but I still can't see where it explains how to get full sub-objects in one call.

Edit: Scratch that, $expand is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Just and FYI, there are already a number of questions on this site with answers to this exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! `/sites/ecengprodsoft/mt/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TeamCalendar?$expand=Attendees`

Comment: did u see that the answer was on my link?! :)

Comment: It helped, but I found it via another Google search :P